# Is there a better Solr and P2P integration option?

Tags: web-services, solr, p2p, jxta

In thinking about my applications network service needs using the Java language I've more or less boiled it down to a combination of using Solr, P2P and REST. An automated notifier service would be good to include too.

Although I like JXTA I'm not sure it is doing so well these days after the Oracle Java buyout, apparently there is now a Chaupel project but it looks inactive for the most part. Solr on the other hand is doing very well.

Since my network is for the most part based on Solr and now a P2P API that is struggling (JXTA) I'm wondering if there are other alternatives for implementing a P2P like layer. Essentially, I want users to be able to post and search/retrieve documents from centralized server based Solr index/s PLUS be able to make user peer groups and collaborate anytime which in my mind seems to be activity that is decentralized.

Maybe what I have in mind for the P2P functionality can be done through a server too? Are there any Solr and P2P projects in the works? I keep hearing about Apache Camel these days, is it of any use in my scenario? Besides the MsgConnect API which has a licensing fee are there any active and robust P2P APIs that I could trust enough to include with my application?

Comment: JXTA is still alive. A company called OneDrum is still maintaining the 2.6 branch alive by posting patches.

Comment: How is Chaupel doing? Can it be used in production yet/soon?

Comment: I have not have much time to work on it recently. It is not production ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for p2p middlaweres, check out FreePastry, XMPP and some other JMS compatible, like Java JMS, ActiveMQ, HornetQ. And about the Sorl, you can use it on them, i do not think that already exists a p2p middleware with native integration with sorl.